# Double Nesting defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

Poked around but couldn't figure it out, probably a very simple solution but please help me understand.

Source (sample.txt):

```
1,1,2,3
2,3,2,4,4
```

This:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

input = "sample.txt"

with open(input) as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    rlabel = 1

    for row in r:
        d[rlabel].append(row)
        rlabel += 1

print(d)
```

Gets This:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [['1', '1', '2', '3']], 2: [['2', '3', '2', '4', '4']]})
```

Why are there double brackets around my lists?

Comment: Because `row` is also a list. If that's not what you want, try `d[rlabel].extend(row)`. Alternatively, given that `rlabel` is just a 1-based index of the row, look into using `enumerate` - I'm not sure you need a `defaultdict` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are there double brackets around my lists?

Your code works exactly as expected. The key point is the usage of `extend` and `append`.

- [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.append) adds the parameter you passed as a single element. Due to a list is an object and your defaultdict class is list, so the list is appended as a list of lists.
- [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.extend) method iterate in the input and extend the original list by adding all elements from an iterable.

So, in this case, if you want to add a single list to your defaultdict you should use `list.extend` method. And your output will be:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['1', '1', '2', '3'], 2: ['2', '3', '2', '4', '4']})
```

Answer (score 0):

With a defaultdict, when a key is created a default value is associated to it

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 'a' in d[1]
False
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: []})
```

Given that your row is a list, you are appending a list to the list associated with the key.
To add the elements you can do

```
d[rlabel]+= row
```